# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ so that f will be continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$

Tags: limits, functions

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ so that the function will be continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{6}{x-4} & x<-2 \\
a-bx & -2\le x \le1 \\
\dfrac{x-1}{\sqrt (x)-1} & x>1
\end{cases}
$$

I am able to recognize the following conditions,

- $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty,-2]$
- $f$ is continuous on $[1,\infty)$